# Moq: Verifying if a void was called without actually executing its code

Tags: moq

I have the following class with a method that I want to test using Moq:

```
public class TestClass: ITestClass
{
        // ...
    public void ProcessAutomaticFillRequest(FillRequestParamDataContract fillRequestParam)
    {
        //...

        NotificationServer.Instance.Publish(channel, fillRequestParam);
    }
```

In my test I have the following:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void CanFillRequest()
    {
        // ...

        _notificationServer.Setup(ns => ns.Publish(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<FillRequestParamDataContract>())).Verifiable();
        _TestClass.ProcessAutomaticFillRequest(fillRequestParam);
        _notificationServer.Verify(ns => ns.Publish(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<FillRequestParamDataContract>()), Times.Once);
    }
```

The problem is that I want to test if Publish is called but without actually running the code inside the Publish method, because it has too many dependencies that I cannot mock. I thought that putting Verifiable() would do it but I get exceptions thrown by the dependencies. All I want to do is test if the call to Publish will be done but without running its code during the test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to pass the `NotificationServer` instance for it to call the mocked method otherwise it will call the method for the instance returned by `NotificationServer.Instance`. Something like below should work. You can also pass the instance in the constructor if it makes sense.

```
[TestMethod]
public void CanFillRequest()
{
    var _notificationServer = new Mock<NotificationServer>();
    _TestClass.ProcessAutomaticFillRequest(fillRequestParam, _notificationServer.Object);

// Below change "string" to whatever the type for channel is.
    _notificationServer.Verify(ns => ns.Publish(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<FillRequestParamDataContract>()), Times.Once);
}

public class TestClass : ITestClass
{
    // ...
    public void ProcessAutomaticFillRequest(FillRequestParamDataContract fillRequestParam, NotificationServer _notificationServer)
    {
        //...

        _notificationServer.Publish(channel, fillRequestParam);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand, why do I have to add the method ProcessAutomaticFillRequest to the test class? This is the method I'm testing ("Act" part of AAA). And that only takes the one parameter FillRequestParamDataContract. Anyways, your code helped me advance a little because now I get an error saying that the method was invoked 0 times when I expect it to be invoked once. It's strange because when I debug the test, the breakpoint clearly reaches the line that executes Publish. But the test tells me it was invoked 0 times. Is there something I'm not seeing?

Comment: I couldn't test because don't have all of your classes used. I just updated the test in the answer try now. Just make sure to change string to whatever type the channel is of.